# Twitter API throws back error message for exceeding rate-limits days after the last call

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, rate-limiting, twitterapi-python

I have some python code that connects to the Twitter API (standard v1.1) and searches for tweets based on a search key word. Everything was functioning smoothly until last Monday, where I got a message when running my code, saying:

***“Request exceeds account’s current package request limits. Please upgrade your package and retry or contact Twitter about enterprise access.”***

I waited for 48 hours and tried again a couple of minutes ago and I still get the same error message. This seems to be impossible as according to the API Documentation I am far from reaching any sort of limit, plus limits are set to intervals and I did nothing for 48 hours.

Any ideas how I can fix this and carry on with my research?

Comment: What endpoint are you calling exactly? That error does not sound like an error from the standard v1.1 API. Are you using premium search? Can you share the code that is generating this error?

Answer (score 0):

For Twitter API (Standard v1.1) the rate limit for endpoint search/tweets is **180** Requests/window per user, and **450** Requests/window per app.

If you are calling API in a loop, then make sure your loop will not exceed 180 within 15min of interval.

[Standard API Rate limit](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rate-limits)